# Prevent scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, position

I have this div, and i need it to be fixed, but i can't use position fixed (the site goes to the left when i push a button, and if the div it's fixed, t will stay in the same spot)... How can i do it?

```
#baar{
height: 56px;
width: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3 0%, #f9f9f9 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3 0%, #f9f9f9 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3 0%, #f9f9f9 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, #e3e3e3 0%, #f9f9f9 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #e3e3e3 0%, #f9f9f9 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #f9f9f9), color-stop(1, #e3e3e3));
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #e3e3e3 0%, #f9f9f9 100%);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
position: relative;
margin-top: 16px;
left: 0;
text-align: center;
}
```

I've already tried overflow: hidden...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
position: absolute;
```

and check if that works, also maybe add a float parameter.

Have a look at this documentation/syntax of style sheets on w3schools, it can be helpful if you forget a couple things now and again.
-http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

Comment: I would have commented this on yours but I don't have enough rep/points to do so yet. But try it out! :)

Comment: it works horizontally, but vertically it doesn't fix... But thanks anyway... It scrolls with the rest...